# To download and convert csv file to Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I have a requirement where i need to download a csv file from given url and then export the data from file to database.

Is there any way to download and convert the file directly to datatable rather than saving it to harddisk and then reading it to datatable.

Hope my question make some sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why writing it to the harddisk and not in a memory stream?

Comment: Yes, you can send request to some site and read its response without writing it to disk.

Comment: You need to specify what you have done and what you have tried. Simply "How Do I...." questions don't work here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the overall objective? Speed or ease of coding?  What is the size of data?  Bulk importing CSV is pretty quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StreamReader class to download csv without the need to save it locally:

```
public string DownloadCSV(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest .GetResponse();

    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse .GetResponseStream());
    string results = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    streamReader .Close();

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string FileName = ...
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection
       ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + 
         Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) + 
         "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");

conn.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
       ("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(FileName), conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet("Temp");
adapter.Fill(ds);

conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written five methods below.

They have been designed to take into account optional quote marks (e.g. " symbols) and to be as versatile as possible without using other libraries:

```
    public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string filePath, bool isHeadings)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser TextFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
            {
                if (isHeadings)
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParser(TextFieldParser);

                }
                else
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParserNoHeadings(TextFieldParser);

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsvString(string csvBody, bool isHeadings)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            MemoryStream MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();


            StreamWriter StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(MemoryStream);

            StreamWriter.Write(csvBody);

            StreamWriter.Flush();


            MemoryStream.Position = 0;


            using (TextFieldParser TextFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(MemoryStream))
            {
                if (isHeadings)
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParser(TextFieldParser);

                }
                else
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParserNoHeadings(TextFieldParser);

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromRemoteCsv(string url, bool isHeadings)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            StreamReader StreamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

            using (TextFieldParser TextFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(StreamReader))
            {
                if (isHeadings)
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParser(TextFieldParser);

                }
                else
                {
                    MethodResult = GetDataTableFromTextFieldParserNoHeadings(TextFieldParser);

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }


    private static DataTable GetDataTableFromTextFieldParser(TextFieldParser textFieldParser)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            textFieldParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

            textFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;


            string[] ColumnFields = textFieldParser.ReadFields();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (string ColumnField in ColumnFields)
            {
                DataColumn DataColumn = new DataColumn(ColumnField);

                DataColumn.AllowDBNull = true;

                dt.Columns.Add(DataColumn);

            }


            while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] Fields = textFieldParser.ReadFields();


                for (int i = 0; i < Fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Fields[i] == "")
                    {
                        Fields[i] = null;

                    }

                }

                dt.Rows.Add(Fields);

            }

            MethodResult = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }

    private static DataTable GetDataTableFromTextFieldParserNoHeadings(TextFieldParser textFieldParser)
    {
        DataTable MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            textFieldParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

            textFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            bool FirstPass = true;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] Fields = textFieldParser.ReadFields();

                if(FirstPass)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Fields.Length; i++)
                    {
                        DataColumn DataColumn = new DataColumn("Column " + i);

                        DataColumn.AllowDBNull = true;

                        dt.Columns.Add(DataColumn);

                    }

                    FirstPass = false;

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < Fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (Fields[i] == "")
                    {
                        Fields[i] = null;

                    }

                }

                dt.Rows.Add(Fields);

            }

            MethodResult = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }
```

If, like me, you're saving from reporting services then you should use it like this:

```
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamids;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string filenameExtension;

    byte[] bytes = rvMain.ServerReport.Render("csv", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

    string CsvBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

    DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromCsvString(CsvBody,true);
```

Otherwise, all you need do is:

```
    bool IsHeadings = true; //Does the data include a heading row?

    DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromCsvString(CsvBody, IsHeadings);
```

Or to use directly from a csv file

```
    bool IsHeadings = true; //Does the data include a heading row?

    DataTable dt = GetDataTabletFromCsvFile(FilePath, IsHeadings)
```

Or to use a csv file that is stored remotely

```
    bool IsHeadings = true; //Does the data include a heading row?

    DataTable dt = GetDataTabletFromRemoteCsv(Url, IsHeadings)
```